# IPad Button DropDown with PopOver Control

Tags: ipad, drop-down-menu, uitableview, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet

I am developing an iPad app and I am trying to implement a series of drop down lists in my app. I have a custom button that is a cell on the UITableViewController. So whenever the button is tapped, it should show a list of options that the user can select and it should set the selected value as button's title. I tried to implement picker view but didn't like it on the iPad. I also tried to implement action sheet and pop over controllers but failed to get the result.

Of all the examples I referred to, it shows how to display popover controllers from bar button item on toolbar or navigation bar but I didn't find any which shows me the implementation for the custom buttons on tableview as one of the rows.

Can someone please guide me on this. If possible a sample code or a tutorial will be of great help.

Thanks for all your time.

Answer (score 1):

I have placed my code in the following link. You can refer it.

[problem in setting PopoverContentSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527408/problem-in-setting-popovercontentsize)