# setPopoverContentSize not working

Tags: ios, ipad, ios4, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UIPopoverController` in a view, and the following method to update its `CGSize`:

```
-(void)updatePop:(CGSize)newSize
{
    NSLog(@"New Size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(newSize));    
    [popoverSearch setPopoverContentSize:newSize animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"popoverContentSize: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(popoverSearch.popoverContentSize));
}
```

When the method runs, the console shows the following:

```
New Size: {320, 640}
popoverContentSize: {320, 409}
```

Does anyone have idea why it's happening? It happens specially in landscape...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having a similar problem in that I was unable to change the size of a popover controller during device rotation.  I found the information that lead to my solution in a [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874146/close-uipopover-on-rotation-with-a-fadeout-animation).

Because I was presenting the popover from a Bar button, UIKit was "trying" to help by adjusting the size of the popover during rotation (because the position of the button might be different after a change to a different device orientation). Even though I knew exactly what size I wanted the popover to be in every case, it wasn't respecting my calls to setPopoverContentSize.  My solution was to dismiss the popover in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation, then re-present the same popover in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation after setting appropriate values for both contentSizeForViewInPopover and popoverContentSize. IHTH

Comment: Good idea, didn't think about this before. Thanks!