# Animate popoverContentsize when pushing navigation view controller in popover on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

#### How do I get my UIPopoverController to animate its size when its contained UINavigationController pushes a new controller?

I have a `UIPopover` being displayed from a `UIBarButtonItem` in my iPad app.  It contains a `UINavigationViewController`, which has a sort of settings window as its root view controller.  The settings window is a subclass of `UITableViewController` (style set to grouped), and tapping any of its cells pushes different "chooser" view controllers on the nav controller that are also subclasses of `UITableViewController`.

For each of the chooser views, in `viewDidAppear`, I'm setting `contentSizeForViewInPopover` appropriately:

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, self.items.count * 44);
```

But it doesn't animate the change; when the navigation animation finishes, the popover snaps to the new height (width never changes from 320).  Navigating backward animates the size change (accomplished with the technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5032887/412107)), but forward never does.

I've tried obtaining a reference to the popover it's in and using `setPopoverContentSize:animated:` but it doesn't work.  I've looked at [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105548/setpopovercontentsize-not-working) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527408/problem-in-setting-popovercontentsize) to no avail.

How do I get it to always animate the size change properly?

**Update:** I've set up a simple test project to try this out.  It's a tab bar application for iPad set up in Xcode.  I added a tab bar item to the navigation bar in one of the view controllers.  When that button is pressed, the controller presents a popover that contains a navigation controller that has a very simple `UITableViewController` subclass, called `TestContentViewController`, as its root view controller.

In `viewDidLoad` of that subclass, I randomly generate a number of items:

```
self.numItems = arc4random() % 10 + 3;
```

This is my number of rows; number of sections is 1.  In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I just set the cell's label text and return it.  When a row is selected, I generate another instance of the same class and push it on the stack.

Without doing anything at all with the `contentSizeForViewInPopover` property on any VC, the popover just goes to its maximum height and stays there no matter how many rows are in my table view.

If I set the size in viewDidAppear, like this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, self.numItems * 44);
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
{
```

- When the popover first appears, it flashes very quickly to full height and then snaps to the height I set.
- When a new controller is pushed on the navigation controller, it snaps to its height with no animation.
- When I navigate back, if the VC that I'm popping to is taller than the one I'm popping from, it animates to the correct size.  If what I'm popping to is smaller, it does nothing.

If I do the same thing but in `viewWillAppear`:

- When the popover first appears, it's full-height
- When I first tap a row and get a new controller on the stack, it animates to a minimum of about 400px tall.  When a new controller is pushed on the stack, if it needs more height it gets it.  If not it stays at what it was before.

If I do the same thing in `viewDidLoad`, it's basically the same as `viewWillAppear` except it appears at the right size at first.

I've tried setting the nav controller's delegate to be the VC that presents the popover, and then set the popover's height (`setPopoverContentSize:animated:`) in `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:`, but the resultant height is off by a little bit.  I think the size I set there needs to take into account the extra height of the navigation bar built into the top of the popover.  And the animation when pushing a new controller on the stack is weird.

**Update again:** See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719625/how-can-i-make-uipopoverpresentationcontroller-resize-on-navigation-pop) for the same problem solved with the newer `UIPopoverPresentationController`.

Comment: @Jefferson, have to tried setting the popoverContentSize for the navigationcontroller used as the contentViewController of the Popover?

Comment: @8Ours - Yep, I just tried that and it makes the popover go to full height when a new VC is pushed on the nav controller. No luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to do the following for all **UITableViewController**, I tried it and it works for me!

```
- (void)setSize:(BOOL)fake
{
    CGSize view_size;
    int sections_height, rows_height;

    //if you dynamically change the number of visible rows
    //for example overriding numberOfRowsInSection:section
    //this can help you to evaluate the correct popover height
    int sections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
    int rows = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sections; i++){
        rows += [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
    }
    sections_height = sections * 30 /*section height*/;
    rows_height = rows * 44 /*row height*/;

    view_size = CGSizeMake(320 /*fixed width*/, sections_height + rows_height);

    if(fake){
        view_size.width -= 1;
        view_size.height -= 1;
    }

    [self setContentSizeForViewInPopover:view_size];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //...    
    [self setSize:FALSE];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setSize:TRUE];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self setSize:FALSE];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: This appears to work.  I had to modify the math a little bit for my specific situation, though.

Comment: @Mr.Jefferson do you think I deserve the reward? :)

Comment: Waiting on JP.  If his solution ends up working, it's cleaner.  If not, it's all yours.

Comment: Amazing that it has to be done this way, but your solution worked very well for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you were close if you tried keeping a reference to the popoverController and used `setPopoverContentSize:animated:`

What works for me is this combination of `setPopoverContentSize:animated:` AND `contentSizeForViewInPopover` in that specific order, for each controller your put on the stack:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.popoverController setPopoverContentSize:whateverSize animated:true];
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = whateverSize;
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

In this case, self.popoverController is a reference I keep in each controllers that is pushed on the stack, it would probably be cleaner to use a singleton variable for that.

Comment: I've tried this, and it looks like the table view animates to the proper height, but the popover itself still snaps to the new height.

Comment: then it must be something specific to your project, do you have a sample project we could troubleshoot? I created a sample project with the code above and my popovers are resizing with animation

Comment: I tried this in a sample project, but I don't know where to post it for download.

Comment: I probably do not understand the problem, or we're not using the same iOS version (I am using iOS6), but I ran your code and the popover animates to the new height every single time I am pressing a row or press back to go up one level..

Answer (score 0):

If animation is what you seek, you can try the following piece of code. Honestly speaking, I have no experience in iPad development, but I use it to animate frame and alpha changes in almost all my projects.
The Parameters are simple, you have, in order, the duration over which animation occurs, time delay, animation options, the block where you specify the changes in view, and another block object where you specify the aftermath.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
               self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, self.items.count * 44);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                //Insert what you need to do after the animation is over
                 }];
```

You can try putting it in the *-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated*

Try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: This animation code is more for custom animations; I'm trying to get the system to perform its own animations.

Comment: Oh ok. Like I said, really not an iPad dev. But glad you got the answer from Francesco Vadicamo.